# Hibernate Caching Technique

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, struts, in-memory-database

I have a application which has 200 tables - classified into 4 groups

1. Non Transactional (50 tables) - Tables like department, designation etc which are updated once a while sometime by admin (100000 reads : 1write ratio & 1write/month)
2. Less Transactional (50 tables) - tables like settings, product, tax rates which are read more and inserted very less often but write occurs everyday (1000 reads : 1 write ratio & 1 write/day)
3. Transactional (50 tables) -tables like orders, receipts etc which are written and read almost equally (10 reads : 1 write & 1 write/hr)
4. Heavy Transactional (50 tables) - tables like tasks, history etc which are written more and read less but used by services & reports (1 read : 1 writes & 1 write/minute)

I am using hibernate, struts2 & spring and looking for caching strategy to get best performance & efficiency.

If you observe i have more data in tables which are written & read most, so caching them in more critical.

Can I cache group 4 tables? If yes how ?

Can I cache group 3 tables? If yes how ?

Can I cache group 2 tables? If yes how ?

Can I cache group 1 tables? If yes how ?

Can I use in memory db for some tables?

Will view help me in some cases? Which cases?

**Well what I want finally is a fast read access from in memory database, some thing that will update my in-memory database as database changes. Like say I have products list, orders list in memory but when any new product or order gets added this list must reload themselves. Typically all reads from some in-memory database while all writes to direct db with trigger to update list or list-item.**

Comment: If your higest activity is 1 operation per minute, I seriously doubt caching is important. Databases are incredibly fast, and 1 read/write per minute is very unlikely to overwhelm your database. Only optimize if you have a performance problem, and if you have measured and proven that caching is the solution. Else, you'll add add complexity for nothing.

Comment: No its just a ball mark figure per user per table, there will be 100 users & multiple tables.......Need to be more n more fast basically :) As even if its not a very high scale system but to serve one request we have to reduce the response time to as low as possible.

Comment: You is using Hibernate specific API or JPA with Hibernate as implementation?

Comment: Hibernate specific api. No jpa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets start with the thumb rule of caching,

**Cache the non-transactional data which are read frequently and change rarely**.

Hibernate allows you to get there pretty safely. From this point even though still you can use caching it is not really recommended as you might run in to multiple problems with it. So it better to proceed with caution on this. Have a look at the below list of articles, it will give you more insight.

1. [Hibernate: Truly Understanding the Second-Level and Query Caches](https://web.archive.org/web/20190719063218/https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)
2. [Understanding Caching in Hibernate – The Second Level Cache](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/)
3. [Improving Hibernate's Performance](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=353736)

So when we apply this rule to your scenario, Only the first set should get cached. Do that first, **measure your application for performance improvement.** If things are fine you can consider caching the second group also. It is not recommended to cache the transactional tables so the set 3 and 4 are ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

Though ManuPk has answered the question in a very detailed manner,i just want to add a few things, Hibernate provides a local InProc cache that cannot be used in a multi-server environment. so during the peak load times, if the response time is not good and you feel that performance is an issue, you better go for a 2 Level cache. because it allows applications using NHibernate to now scale to multi-server environments and also remove any database bottlenecks. Please read the following article for further reference, though its about NHibernate(.NET)but it'll explain the concept of L1 and L2 cache.

[Secondary Level cache, Taking performance ot the next level](http://distributedcaching.blog.com/2012/04/26/secondary-l2-cache-with-nhibernate-%E2%80%93-taking-performance-to-the-next-level/)

you can use [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/index.html) as a second level cache as it is now fully compatible with Java and .NET apps.
Cheers